# RunTimeError, Tkinter и мультипоточность

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет, tkinter

Создаю чат-сервер на socket и threading + tkinter
Использую TCP/IP, server <-> client

Как я понял ошибка из-за особеностей ткинтера, но всё решения что я нашел в сети были индивидуальними.

Сама ошибка:

```
Exception in thread SendThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Davyd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\restico_project\Python\chat_app\client.py", line 21, in send
    data = entry.get()
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3038, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Код сервера:

```
import time
import socket
import tkinter as tk
import threading as th

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='#ffcA70')
root.title('SERVER')
root.geometry('500x500+550+200')
root.resizable(False, False)

def get():
    while True:
        data = con.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if data != ' ':
            label_text = display_text.get() + '\n'
            text['text'] = label_text + data


def send():
    data = entry.get()
    if data != ' ':
        send_data = time.strftime('[%x %X] :: ') + data
        con.send((send_data).encode('utf-8'))
        label_text = display_text.get()
        text = label_text + '\n[ YOU ] ' + send_data


send_thread = th.Thread(target=send, name='SendThread', daemon=True)
get_thread = th.Thread(target=get, name='GetThread', daemon=True)

display_text = tk.StringVar()
text = tk.Label(root, width=35, height=16, bg='#ffe5b3', font="Arial 14",
               justify='left', anchor='sw', textvariable=display_text)
text.pack(side='top', pady=10)

wrap = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Enter text...', bg='#ffcA70')
entry = tk.Entry(wrap, width=48, bg='#f1eee9')
send_but = tk.Button(wrap, width=19, height=2, text='Send', bg='#e7a54f', command=send)

wrap.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=1, ipadx=2)
entry.pack(side='left')
send_but.pack(side='left')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 2020))
s.listen(1)

con, addr = s.accept()

send_thread.start()
get_thread.start()

send_thread.join()
get_thread.join()

root.mainloop()
```

Код клиента:

```
import time
import socket
import tkinter as tk
import threading as th

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='#ffe5b3')
root.title('CLIENT')
root.geometry('500x500+550+200')
root.resizable(False, False)

def get():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if data != ' ':
            label_text = display_text.get() +'\n'
            text['text'] = label_text + data


def send():
    data = entry.get()
    if data != ' ':
        send_data = time.strftime('[%x %X] :: ') + data
        s.send((send_data).encode('utf-8'))
        label_text = display_text.get()
        text = label_text + '\n[ YOU ] ' + send_data

send_thread = th.Thread(target=send, name='SendThread', daemon=True)
get_thread = th.Thread(target=get, name='GetThread', daemon=True)

display_text = tk.StringVar()
text = tk.Label(root, width=35, height=16, bg='#f1eee9', font="Arial 14",
               justify='left', anchor='sw', textvariable=display_text)
text.pack(side='top', pady=10)

wrap = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Enter text...', bg='#ffe5b3')
entry = tk.Entry(wrap, width=48, bg='#f1eee9')
send_but = tk.Button(wrap, width=19, height=2, text='Send', bg='#e7a54f' , command=send)
wrap.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=1, ipadx=2)
entry.pack(side='left')
send_but.pack(side='left')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.103', 2020))

send_thread.start()
get_thread.start()

send_thread.join()
get_thread.join()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не помню как в Питоне, но обычно нигде нельзя работать с GUI не из основного потока.

Comment: Ну собственно да https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237067/how-to-make-tkinter-gui-thread-safe

Comment: спасибо, полезно узнать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CrazyElf:

Не помню как в Питоне, но обычно нигде нельзя работать с GUI не из основного потока.

Варианты решения этой проблемы для `tkinter` можно [посмотреть здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237067/how-to-make-tkinter-gui-thread-safe)